# Is there any way in Java to take image width and height without transfer or download?

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

In order to get image's height we can use **[`ImageIO.read(new URL("…")).getHeight()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getHeight--)**.

My questions:

1. Do I understand correctly that this method downloads the image to the local computer prior size calculation?
2. If yes, to where exactly the image is downloaded — to some JVM's cache on HDD or directly to the RAM?
3. Is there any way to take image's height without transfer or download? But with some kind of request to server?

Comment: there is no `ImageIO.read()` method

Comment: @wero, of course I mean something like `ImageIO.read(new URL("%IMG_URL%")).getHeight();`

Comment: the answer is in the `ImageIO.read(URL)` Javadoc and implementation. The JDK ships with source code.

Comment: `ImageIO.read` returns a `BufferedImage`; that alone should already answer your question(s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, your questions:

1. Kind of. First of all, the `ImageIO.read(...)` methods, are convenience methods that will decode the *first* image in a file, using all default parameters for decoding. As all `ImageIO.read(...)` operations are delegated to format specific plugins or `ImageReader` instances (like `JPEGImageReader`), this *may* be plugin specific. But the general case, is that the image data is transferred and decoded "on the fly". Note that there's no "size calculation" here, rather the *entire image* is decoded to a `BufferedImage` in this case. As much data as is needed to decode the first image in the file has to be *transferred*, but not necessarily *stored* anywhere on the computer, other than the decoded pixel values.
2. It depends. There's a setting `ImageIO.setUseCache(boolean)`, that controls whether the data is cached on disk or in RAM.

- If the setting is `true`, the data is temporarily stored on disk, typically in the default temp directory (see `java.io.tempdir` System property).
- If the setting is `false` the data is temporarily stored in memory while the image is decoded.

3. No, not unless your server has a special API to give you this data, and you perform specific requests against this API. However, the `ImageIO` API does have a lot more granular methods that allows you to get the image dimensions a lot faster, and without downloading/decoding the entire image up front.

The faster way of obtaining the image dimensions is:

```
try (InputStream stream = url.openStream()) {
    // The "useCache" setting will decide whether "input" below 
    // will be disk or memory cached
    try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream)) {
         ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next(); // TODO: Handle no reader
         try {
             reader.setInput(input);

             // Get dimensions of first image in the stream, without decoding pixel values
             int width = reader.getWidth(0);
             int height = reader.getHeight(0);
         }
         finally {
             reader.dispose();
         }
    }
 }
```

Again, depending on image format, the above code should only read as much of the header/meta data as is needed to determine the image dimensions. Most `ImageReader` implementations will read all header data for this, but still, it's much faster and involves a lot less data (and memory) than decoding the entire image.

It's hard to make any assumptions as to how much data is or needs to be downloaded, because different formats have headers of varying size, the underlying transport (ie. HTTP) may transfer data in "chunks" etc.

Comment: as to 1), I don't see any way it would be possible to know the image height without downloading the image first (and then examining it), even in theory. Can you elaborate how that would happen?

Comment: Terminology perhaps, but you don't need to fully download the file, *then* start decoding it. The `ImageReader` can start decoding the image as soon as some of the bytes are transferred, and continue decoding while the data is transferring. You only need to transfer enough data to decode the *first* image (if you consider a multi-image file format, like TIFF for example, or images with lots of meta data). Finally, to just get the width/height, most formats store them in a header, and you only need to transfer/decode a few bytes at the beginning of the file (as in my code example).

Comment: @haraldK, is there any way to transfer *just* image headers with width/height meta-data without the whole image download?

Comment: @MikeB. My code above attempts to do just that. It makes no guarantees as to how much is downloaded though. I believe this is the best you can do, without a specific server-side API.

Comment: @haraldK, one more question. In your code there is `reader.dispose();` but there is no stream closing, e.g. `stream.close();`. Is it OK or I have to add call for `close();` in any way?

Comment: @MikeB. Yes, the streams are closed, it's just handled implicit, using the [*try-with-resources*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax. The code should be okay as-is in that regard.

Comment: Great. One more moment, I paid attention that some sites refuse to establish connection (code 403), is there any way to supply user agent and referrer in your approach?

Comment: Replace URL.openStream() with URL.openConnection(), set the appropriate headers and then connection.getInputStream(). PS: StackOverflow tip: Don't continuously expand the topic, instead ask a new question, that focus on the new topic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the `read()` method has to complete and return a value befor the `getHeight()` method can be called.

This isn't even an `ImageIO` question, it is just basic Java syntax and semantics.

Comment: The basic Java syntax doesn’t answer that question, e.g. when [`Toolkit.createImage(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage-java.net.URL-) returns, the image is not necessarily loaded. That’s why [`Image.getHeight(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getHeight-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) might return `-1` and notify the provided `ImageObserver` asynchronously. It’s the `BufferedImage` returned by `ImageIO` which makes the difference.

Comment: My question is not about «basic Java syntax and semantics» but about implementation of `read()`, how and where exactly `BufferedImage` stores the image?

Comment: @Holger That's a documented exception and it only applies when using the overload with an `ImageObserver`.

Comment: @MikeB. In the returned `BufferedImage`, of course.

Comment: @EJP, OK, understood. BTW, is there any way to take image's height without transfer or download? But with some kind of request to server?

Comment: @EJP: actually, the `BufferedImage` is the special case of the more general `Image` class. While `Image` only offers the potentially asynchronous `getHeight(ImageObserver)` method, the `BufferedImage` adds the synchronous `getHeight()` overload.