# How to get the image width and height from url without downloading the full image in Android?

Tags: android, image, url

[Is there any way in Java to take image width and height without transfer or download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925981/is-there-any-way-in-java-to-take-image-width-and-height-without-transfer-or-down)

mentions a way using ImageIO, but ImageIO is not available on Android.

Android has BitmapFactory, which can decode the image to get the width and height without loading the entire image to memory, but it only works with files.

So the question is on Android, is there a way to get just the image width and height from an web url without downloading the entire image?

Comment: check out this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440863/can-i-get-image-file-width-and-height-from-uri-in-android/16440953#16440953

Comment: I found options.inJustDecodeBounds = true only works for files, if the InputStream is from an URL, it is ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Java, using ImageReader.getHeight(int) and ImageReader.getWidth(int) normally only reads the image header so image is not downloaded entirely, not sure it will work in Android:

```
public static Dimension getImageDimensionFromUrl(final URL url)
            throws IOException {

        try (ImageInputStream in = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(url.openStream())) {
            final Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(in);
            if (readers.hasNext()) {
                final ImageReader reader = readers.next();
                try {
                    reader.setInput(in);
                    return new Dimension(reader.getWidth(0), reader.getHeight(0));
                } finally {
                    reader.dispose();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible without downloading the image. `BitmapFactory` cannot be applied unless and until the image is downloaded.

Comment: what if I know for sure the image is in jpeg? the width and height is encoded in the header of the jpeg data, right? can I just read the header?

Comment: what about the inJustDecodeBounds , doesn't that decode for width and height , could we pass input stream from HttpUrlConnection to bitmap factory and use that